# jquery - How to stop an overflow div scroll down when drag an element out of it?

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar

I have two divs: one top, one bottom. Top div has overflow: auto and a scrollbar. When I drag element from top div to bottom div, the scrollbar auto scroll down. I know this is a normal behaviour but I want to stop that.

Screenshot: http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/5235/simplezttpleditor.jpg

Answer (score 0):

onDragStart,

```
$('#topDivId').css({overflow: 'hidden'});
```

onDragEnd,

```
 $('#topDivId').css({overflow: 'auto'});
```

Just set overflow to hidden while dragging.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a quick play around with a similar situation and came up with a hacky solution:

onDragStart:
Make the item absolutely positioned and a child of the body element. It then moves over the top of everything else.

onDragEnd:
Add the item back to the correct parent and make it relatively positioned again.

Not sure if this helps in your situation but it works in Safari for me.